# Can we regrow chopped purple poui tree

Tags: trees

A new gardener chopped down our 1 year old purple poui (Tabebuia impetiginosa) tree!! He clearly didn't have a clue about what he was doing...we asked him to trim the branches and cut the top as the tree had grown higher than our 1 story house.  Instead he topped the tree at 5 feet from the ground and removed all the lower branches. Will it regrow or should we just finish chopping it down and remove it?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by 'purple pour tree'  -  do you have the botanical name or another well known common name for the tree?

Comment: Sorry, I meant purple "poui"....spell check issue :(

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it will grow again as it's not an evergreen.  But perhaps you can save it if this only happened a few days ago.

https://www.thespruce.com/how-to-make-a-cleft-graft-3269523

> I can also imagine trying to use a cleft graft on whole tree stumps, to make use of the root system or to save the tree. If you have to lose a mature (though perhaps not enormous) tree that you have an affection for, a cleft graft is one way to sort-of resurrect it.
>
> You could take suitable twigs off a healthy part of the crown, cut the tree down, and then join the twigs to the stump via a cleft graft. You would then have literally replaced the tree with itself: a practical or sentimental alternative to replacing it.

Comment: Thanks, but there are no twigs...this was a very young tree, barely 1 and a half years old and it was stripped bare of branches and then chopped down.  Guess we'll just have to wait and see if it springs again.

Comment: You can't find another tree locally to take a branch from?

Comment: We've been getting a lot of rain here in the Caribbean and I'm happy to say that the tree is sprouting!! Will watch and see how well it does.